# How to pull every single image (tag or untagged) from AWS ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

My target is to copy every single image from each repository from one region and push them into another region.
I have the following script that does that, however it only pulls the "latest" images.

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION="us-west-2"
DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_REGION="us-west-2"
DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_BASE_PATH="123456.dkr.ecr.$DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_REGION.amazonaws.com/"


REPO_LIST=($(aws ecr describe-repositories --query 'repositories[].repositoryUri' --output text --region $TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION))
REPO_NAME=($(aws ecr describe-repositories --query 'repositories[].repositoryName' --output text --region $TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION))


for repo_url in ${!REPO_LIST[@]}; do
        echo "star pulling image ${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]} from Target account"
        docker pull ${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]}


        # Create repo in destination account, remove this line if already created
        aws ecr create-repository --repository-name ${REPO_NAME[$repo_url]}
        docker tag   ${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]} $DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_BASE_PATH/${REPO_NAME[$repo_url]} 
        docker push $DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_BASE_PATH/${REPO_NAME[$repo_url]} 
done
```

This does not take every image into count. Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating over tags for each repository:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e  # -e quit on error

ACCOUNT_ID="123456"
TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION="us-west-1"
DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_REGION="us-west-2"
DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_BASE_PATH="$ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_REGION.amazonaws.com/"

REPO_LIST=($(aws ecr describe-repositories --query 'repositories[].repositoryUri' --output text --region $TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION))
REPO_NAME=($(aws ecr describe-repositories --query 'repositories[].repositoryName' --output text --region $TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION))

for repo_url in "${!REPO_LIST[@]}"; do
    # Create repository. Throws an error when a repository exists;
    # could be extracted into a separate function which checks
    # for presence beforehand / ignores the RepositoryAlreadyExistsException
    # We could also remove the -e flag, risking missing errors on other parts of the script
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "${REPO_NAME[$repo_url]}" --region $DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_REGION

    echo "== Start copying images from ${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]} to ${DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_BASE_PATH}${REPO_NAME[$repo_url]}"
    IMAGE_TAGS=($(aws ecr list-images --repository-name ${REPO_NAME[$repo_url]} --query 'imageIds[].imageTag' --output text --region $TARGET_ACCOUNT_REGION))
    for tag in "${!IMAGE_TAGS[@]}"; do
        IMAGE_SRC="${REPO_LIST[$repo_url]}:${IMAGE_TAGS[$tag]}"
        IMAGE_DEST="$DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_BASE_PATH${REPO_NAME[$repo_url]}:${IMAGE_TAGS[$tag]}"
        echo "-- Copying image $IMAGE_SRC"
        docker pull $IMAGE_SRC
        docker tag $IMAGE_SRC $IMAGE_DEST
        docker push $IMAGE_DEST
    done
done
```